# http-proxy forward to a specific path

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

While trying out http-proxy with node.js, I have the following piece of code:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createServer(
  require('proxy-by-url')({
  '/AAA': { port: 80, host: 'myDomain.com' },
  '/BBB': { port: 80, host: 'myDomain.com' }
  })
).listen(8000);
```

Obviously all requests to `http://localhost:8000/AAA` and `http://localhost:8000/BBB` are proxied to `http://myDomain.com`

I'm trying to proxy the requests to `http://localhost:8000/AAA` to `http://myDomain.com/AAA/rss.xml` but cannot figure out how to set that up.

I tried with:

```
'/AAA': { port: 80, host: 'myDomain.com/AAA/rss.xml' }
```

but it is throwing exceptions.

```
'/AAA': { port: 80, host: 'myDomain.com', url: '/AAA/rss.xml' }
```

or

```
'/AAA': { port: 80, host: 'myDomain.com', path: '/AAA/rss.xml' }
```

are inefficiency.

Does someone has an idea on how to set that up?

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, perhaps look into haproxy. With its ACL, you can perform the path-based routing you want without worrying about performance.